# AWS AppSync: Graphql Schema Stitching? Schema in multiple files?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

When I'm using the **AWS .NET CDK** for infrastructure as code, I find it beneficial to split my **GraphQL schema** into multiple files and merge them during stack creation. This approach offers a more organized and manageable way to integrate **AWS AppSync**. Is there a recommended method or best practice for achieving this with the AWS .NET CDK? I'd love to hear some insights and examples.